# Rally Python API Associate a changeset to an artifact

Tags: python, api, rally

I am trying to associate a dummy changeset that I have created to an existing artifact by using the python api provided by Rally.

Please refer to the follow code, any help is appreciated!

Thanks

```
user = rally.getUserInfo(name='Dummy Name').pop(0)

artifactName = "FirstDefect"
artifact = rally.get('Artifact', query='Name = %s' % artifactName, instance=True)


#print artifact.details()
changeset_fields = {
    "Name"              : "Testing Python API - test3",
    "Message"           : "Generating a change set",
    "Author"            :   user.ref,
    "SCMRepository"     : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/scmrepository/19191682647",
    "Revision"          :   "4",
    "CommitTimestamp"   : "2014-05-23T9:15Z",
    "Artifacts"         : artifact.ref
}

try:
    rally.put('Changeset', changeset_fields)
except Exception, details:
    sys.stderr.write('ERROR: %s \n' % details)
    sys.exit(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a python specific example, but here is a payload in a browser REST client that creates a changeset:

```
{"changeset":{
    "Message":"1234 abcd",
    "Artifacts":{"Artifact":"/defect/14537223513"},
    "SCMRepository":"/scmrepository/5960544988",
    "Revision":"1",
    "CommitTimestamp":"2013-10-08"
}}
```

Notice this contstract:

```
"Artifacts":{"Artifact":"/defect/14537223513"}
```